# cryptography using node.js having issues

Tags: cryptography, node.js

newbie question re: nodejs and cryto

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var User = {
  user1: { name: 'bob', salt: 'randomSalt', password: sha1('mypass', this.salt) }
};

function sha1(pass, salt) {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha1', salt).update(pass).digest('hex');
}
```

Why do I have
`console.log(User.user1.password == sha1('mypass', 'randomSalt') //false` ?

Answer (score 4):

Answering to myself:

"classic" javascript gotcha :

the context (this) has changed when sha1 is called from the object.  Therefore, this.salt is "undefined"

Comment: Your diagnosis is correct, though I think your explanation is a little off. You expected `this` to refer to `User`, but it never did; referring to `this.salt` in an argument to `sha1` doesn't matter, because `this.salt` is evaluated before being passed into `sha1`. For `this` to refer to `User`, you'd have to call a function that's attached to the `User` object. This is a great tutorial: http://howtonode.org/what-is-this

Comment: Note that there's no way to define a property on an object, then reference that property elsewhere in the same object definition. So, move the `password:` bit to a second line: `User.password = sha1('mypass', User.salt);`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
function sha1(pass, salt) {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha1', salt).update(pass).digest('hex');
}
var User = { name:'Robin', salt:'mysalt'}
User.password = sha1('mypass', User.salt);
// 'cfbc41a870bb7ddd3d7fcc774dd6d2d5850d5340'
```